# External web links won't open when click them - BB App development

Tags: blackberry

I am developing my first blackberry app, I have strings.xml where I keep all HTML content I may need to display in some screens. I can successfully display the html content but nothing happen when you click the web links.

For example, I have the following  in strings.xml

```
<![CDATA[<a href="http://www.hazcheck.com" style="color:blue;">Hazcheck systems</a>]]>
```

When I load the above string into a screen, I see the link as expected, but, nothing happen when I click it.

I tried to remove CDATA tags, but, it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: what Java code are you using to display this?

Comment: I get the strings from Strings.xml and add them into Hashtable object in class A. And then from another View class I do the following:

                                                                                                                      `String incontent = app.ClassA.get(StringName);
   contentField = new BrowserField();
   contentField.displayContent(incontent, "");

    vfmin.add(contentField);
    add(vfmin);
    vfmin.setFocus();`

vfmin is a VerticalFieldManager

After all, I pushscreen that view